# Enable local account via azuredevops yaml pipeline

Tags: powershell, kubernetes, azure-pipelines, azure-aks

I am trying to enable the local account on an AKS cluster (version 1.24.10) by running commands from an AzureDevOps yaml pipeline.

The “old” az aks command :  `az aks update -g <myresourcegroup> -n <myclustername> --enable-local` used to serve me well to enable a local account on an AKS cluster.
In the yaml pipeline, however, this does not seem to work and I resorted to running the [Set-AzAksCluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.aks/set-azakscluster?view=azps-9.7.1) command from within a AzurePowerShell@5 task

```
      - task: AzurePowerShell@5
    displayName: 'disable-local-account'
    name: disablelocalaccount
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'myazsubscription' 
      ScriptType: InlineScript
      Inline: |
          Set-AzAksCluster -ResourceGroupName myresourcegrp -Name mycluster -DisableLocalAccount
      azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
```

By passing the  -DisableLocalAccount switch to the command we can disable the local account on the cluster.
The enabling of the local account on the cluster just seems to elude me somehow…sigh.

Does anybody know if it is possible to enable the local account using the [Set-AzAksCluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.aks/set-azakscluster?view=azps-9.7.1) command? And if so, what is the correct way to go about this?

Many thanks!

Kind regards,
Morné

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, great spot... The enable flag isn't there. You might want to raise this on the [Azure PowerShell GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/discussions/categories/feature-requests).

As a workaround, the Azure CLI does allow enabling of local accounts.

```bash
az aks update --name cluster --resource-group rg --enable-local-accounts
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-update

Comment: Much obliged GordonBy! I have raised issue 21835 for this. https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/21835

Comment: This has been confirmed to be a bug and is being fixed via pr 21869: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/pull/21869